# post my name with array in mail

Tags: php, mysql

This is the first project in which I am facing a problem with the `mail` function. I want to send the `option` tag value in a mail. At that time I am not getting the of `option` tag but I am taking name of the `select` tag in the array because I want to store multiple values in database, that's why I am using an array. Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem?

This is my code:

```
<select multiple id="00N7F000001F2kO" name="soft_skill[]">
  <option value=""selected disabled>soft Skills</option>
  <option name="Personality Development" value="Personality Development">personality development</option>
  <option name="Communication Skills" value="Communication Skills">communication skills</option>
</select>
```

And my code with `mail` function is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $soft_skill = $_POST['soft_skill'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $about_us = $_POST['about_us'];
    $to = "kuljeet@mightymente.com";
    $subject = "Web Enquiry";
    $message = "................";
    $header = "From:$email"."\r\n"."CC: kuljeetdhiman06@gmail.com";             
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
    {
      echo "";
    } else {
      echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: First you talk about mail, then database? I don't see any database calls. Also, soft_skill is unused, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass the array directly in mail, 
either You should use the implode method and specify any delimiter you wish to use.  If you will select multiple option then by using implode you will get result like `Personality Development , Communication Skills`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $soft_skill= implode("," , $_POST['soft_skill']);
    $question=$_POST['question'];
    $about_us=$_POST['about_us'];
    $to="kuljeet@mightymente.com";
    $subject="Web Enquiry";
    $message="................";
    $header="From:$email"."\r\n"."CC: kuljeetdhiman06@gmail.com";             
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "";
    } else{
        echo "";
    } 
}
```

And i saw you message variable is like

```
$message="................";
```

Here you need to concate all the values using `.=` like,

```
$message = "Name : ".$name."\n\n";
$message.= "Soft Skils : ".$soft_skill."\n\n";
$message.= "Question : ".$question."\n\n";
$message.= "About Us : ".$about_us."\n\n";
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$temp_softSkill=implode(",",$_POST['soft_skill']);
```

Because it is an array so you have to use indexes of soft skill array like  `$_POST['soft_skill'][0]` which one u want

Comment: its not working m  getting  this mail 
Name:- aaa
Business:-aa
soft_skill:
Question:-aa

Comment: are u using $temp_softSkill to write the value like   soft_skill: $temp_softSkill